# Error trying to import TurtleWorld

Tags: python, swampy

I'm trying to run through the python book ThinkingPython and have gotten to the first case study and I can't get the module to load. I'm using python 3.3.2 and swampy 2.1.5 and and using a mac with the  latest OS. When I try to import TurtleWorld I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import TurtleWorld
ImportError: No module named 'TurtleWorld'

I have no idea why this isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure to check that you've properly installed swampy correctly. That would be my first recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

TurtleWorld is imported as:

```
import swampy.TurtleWorld
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try these:

```
pip install swampy
```

If you don't already have pip installed, you could do

```
sudo pip install swampy
```

If neither of these work, then you could download the zip file from [this website.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/swampy)
You would have to unzip the folder and then navigate to install it. This worked for me, the first two didn't but that could just be me.